Logic Apps email with options is not catching the response when using HTML Confirmation Dialog
I am using Logic App's "sending email with option" action from Outlook to send email to users and trigger some actions based on their response to the emails which is clicking on a button.
It is working fine, but when I add the HTML confirmation dialog box, it does not catch the user's info in the response. Means all of the attributes in response (SelectedOption , UserEmailAddress, UserTenantId and UserId) are null.
Has anyone experienced this issue or have a workaround it without need for development?
Here are some references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-email-with-options
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#approvalemailresponse

Thank you
I am expecting to get the user's info on the response after user clicks on any of the options and also confirms the selected option in the confirmation dialog box.
It is working fine when not using HTML message or HTML confirmation box and I am getting user's info in the response.

It is a known issue and limitation with action Send approval email and it is illustrated here (check last row of the table) which says below-

When users click the Actionable Message card options at the top of an email, values for userid, useremailaddress, and usertenantid are retrieved.


If users click an option from the email body, these values remain empty. Additionally, when sending an approval email, the response for userid, useremailaddress, and usertenantid is null.

So you need to use the actionable message action card option instead of HTML confirmation dialog box to get the user information in the response body.
Your designer should look like below-

This will give you actionable message action card only.

